# File sharing solution with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I am working on a web application that will be used to securely share files between individuals. In terms of functionality what I deem important is easy file sharing, good ux, and secure storage. I want to integrate this functionality into my web application. I am working in the Ruby on Rails framework and have played around with carrierwave and Amazon S3 integration but I can't help but wonder if there is not a complete solution out there already.

My question thus is: Are there file sharing open source solutions or paid products out there which I can plug in to my web application that I should be investigating and not build the whole file sharing component from the start? I do not mind paying a fee for this software.

Comment: have you checked out https://www.inkfilepicker.com/

Comment: not yet, thanks I will have a look at it

Answer (score 1):

You could try https://github.com/mischa78/boxroom

> Boxroom is a Rails application that aims to be a simple interface for
>   managing and sharing files in a web browser. It lets users create
>   folders and upload, download and share files. Admins can manage users,
>   groups and permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Caplinked is a virtual data room provider that provides an API which will securely store and share your files / documents between individuals and groups. They also have a [Ruby on Rails SDK](https://github.com/caplinked/caplinked-api-ruby) which seems pretty easy to use. Check out their [developer portal](http://developer.caplinked.com).